# Unexpected keyword argument

Tags: django

Al hacer un create para insertar una nueva fila en la base de datos, me devuelve un error diciendo que

> TestCounter() got an unexpected keyword argument 'modality__name'

También he probado con un sólo guión bajo (**modality_name**) y devuelve el mismo error.
También he probado modality (sin name) pero claro, **debo acceder al nombre, no a la id foránea**. ¿Me explico?

Error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Views.py**

```
userId = 1
questionMod = 'Ciencias'
create10QuestionNumberList = TestCounter.objects.create(user_id=userId,modality__name=questionMod,counter=0,listQuestionsNumbers='1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10')
```

**Models.py:**

```
class Modality(models.Model):
     name=models.CharField('Modalidad',max_length=100, null=True,blank=True)
      

class TestCounter(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
    modality = models.ForeignKey(Modality,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
    counter = models.IntegerField('Contador',null=True,blank=True)
    listQuestionsNumbers = models.TextField('Array números preguntas',null=True,blank=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Tenía que hacerlo en 2 veces. Por un lado utilizando el name, conseguir el ID en el modelo Modality:

```
modID = Modality.objects.filter(name=questionMod)
```

Y después una vez tenemos el ID podemos hacer el create en el otro modelo sin problema:

```
create10QuestionNumberList = TestCounter.objects.create(user_id=username,modality=modID[0],counter=0,listQuestionsNumbers='1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10')
```

Un saludo.

Comment: ¡No olvides aceptar tu respuesta!